# Property '$el' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on a `vue.js 3` project, where I need to refer/get a `div` element in my script by initially declaring a `null` reference like this `const refRouterView = ref(null)` and I am not sure how to make TypeScript aware of `DomElement`.

### Markup updated

```
<template lang="pug">
.flex
  router-view(ref='refRouterView')
     ...
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const refRouterView = ref(null);
const routerViewHeight = ref(500);

const getRouterViewHeight = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    routerViewHeight.value = refRouterView.value?.$el.offsetHeight;
  }, 250);
};

onMounted(() => getRouterViewHeight());
</script>
```

I was getting this error `Object is possibly 'null'` before adding `?` to `refRouterView.value?` which seems like hack and I don't like it. And, after adding `?` I started seeing this error `Property '$el' does not exist on type 'never'.`

I tried adding `HTMLElement` to `const refRouterView : HTMLElement = ref(null);` but that introduce this error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.` which was not solved even after adding `?` to `refRouterView.value?`

Please help!

### More Info

Originally my question was using `div(ref='refRouterView')` and @Thomas's answer solves it but I was using `router-view`. Just for making my question easy to understanding I mentioned `div` instead of `router-view` and that confused us, hence the answer did not solve my issue.

```
<template lang="pug">
  .flex
    div(ref='refRouterView')
      ...
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you `ref` a DOM node, you don't have an `$el` property, the ref directly points to the DOM node:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html

And for the typescript part, you have to define the type like this as the `refRouterView` is a `Proxy` of a certain type:
`const refRouterView = ref<HTMLDivElement>();`

Then you can directly access the attributes:
`refRouterView.value.offsetHeight`

Comment: thanks for helping, I know that `$el` doesn't exist in `<HTMLDivElement>` and it's a vue.js thing. FYI, as expected `const refRouterView = ref<HTMLDivElement>();` did not solve the issue and we getting this error `Property '$el' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'.` Let me know if you if have any suggestions on how to fix my issue.

Comment: @Syed `$el` does not exist in Vue 3 for DOM refs the value is already the DOM node. I updated the answer to reflect that part as well.

Comment: I am sorry! but that's not true. Here is the console.log
 ...... `refRouterView.value.offsetHeight :>>  undefined` ...... 
`refRouterView.value.$el.offsetHeight :>>  408` ...... let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Now I am confused, before you mentioned you get the error that `Property '$el' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'`, now it returns the expected value? It seems I am missing something here as well, I don't know the `pug` template, maybe there it is different, but if you check the link in my answer that is what I described as well...

Comment: sorry! for confusing you - it's my mistake - your answer solves my problem when I use `div` but I am using `router-view`. Just for making my question easy to understanding I mentioned `div(ref='refRouterView')` instead of `router-view(ref='refRouterView')` and that made us confuse. I have upvoted your answer but sorry could not mark it as answer :( I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(this.$refs.refRouterView as Vue & { $el: () => any }).$el.offsetHeight
```

Please refer to it：
[Vetur bug or code error? “property ‘$el’ does not exist on type ‘SVGelement’](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vetur-bug-or-code-error-property-el-does-not-exist-on-type-svgelement/73696/3)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

const refRouterView = ref<typeof RouterView | null>(null)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you ref is an origin Element, then you don't have to access `$el`, you can access the dom directily by `.value`. You need to access `$el` while you are trying to access a custom component, and you need to get the type with `ref<InstanceType<typeof YourComponent> | null>(null)`, here below is an example:

```js
<template>
    <div class="canvas" ref="canvas"></div>
    <knife_map ref="svgContainer" class="knife_map" :style="{ transform: svgPosition }"></knife_map>


</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import knife_map from './components/knife_map.vue';

const canvas = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
onMounted(() => {
  const { width, height }: { [x: string]: number } = svgContainer.value?.$el.getBoundingClientRect()
  const { width: cvs_width, height: cvs_height } = canvas.value?.getBoundingClientRect() || {}
  console.log('width,height', width, height)
  console.log('cvs_width,cvs_height', cvs_width, cvs_height)
})
</script>
```